# ArrayList: Get length of longest string, Get average length of string

Tags: java, arraylist

In Java, I have a method that reads in a text file that has all the words in the dictionary, each on their own line.
It reads each line by using a for loop and adds each word to an ArrayList.
I want to get the length of the longest word (String) in the Array. In addition, I want to get the length of the longest word in the dictionary file. It would probably be easier to split this into several methods, but I don't know the syntax.

So far, the code is have is:

```
public class spellCheck {
static ArrayList <String> dictionary; //the dictonary file


/**
 * load file
 * @param fileName the file containing the dictionary
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void loadDictionary(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

while (in.hasNext())
{

    for(int i = 0; i < fileName.length(); ++i)
    {
        String dictionaryword = in.nextLine();
        dictionary.add(dictionaryword);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.max` to be a start, `String#length` will probably help

Comment: What's that nested loop is doing, and what does `fileName.length()` have to do with the number of strings that you need to read?

Comment: You loop is completely wrong by the way...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, I saw it, oops :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each word is on it's own line, you should be reading the file more like...

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String dictionaryword = in.nextLine();
        dictionary.add(dictionaryword);        
    }

}
```

Remember, if you open a resource, you are responsible for closing.  See [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details...

Calculating the metrics can be done after reading the file, but since your here, you could do something like...

```
int totalWordLength = 0;
String longest = "";
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String dictionaryword = in.nextLine();
    totalWordLength += dictionaryword.length();
    dictionary.add(dictionaryword);        
    if (dictionaryword.length() > longest.length()) {
        longest = dictionaryword;
    }
}

int averageLength = Math.round(totalWordLength / (float)dictionary.size());
```

But you could just as easily loop through the `dictionary` and use the same idea

(nb- I've used local variables, so you will either want to make them class fields or return them wrapped in some kind of "metrics" class - your choice)

Comment: This helped me a lot when put into context! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set a two counters and a variable that holds the current longest word found before you start reading in with your while loop.  To find the average have one counter be incremented by one each time the line is read and have the second counter add up the total number of characters in each word (obviously the total number of characters entered, divided by the total number of words read -- as denoted by the total number of lines -- is the average length of each word.

As for the longest word, set the longest word to be the empty string or some dummy value like a single character.  Each time you read in a line compare the current word with the previously found longest word (using the `.length()` method on the String to find its length) and if its longer set a new longest word found

Also, if you have all this in a file, I'd use a [buffered reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read in your input data

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help

```
    String words  = "Rookie never dissappoints, dont trust any Rookie";
         // read your file to string if you get string while reading then you can use below code to do that.

    String ss[] = words.split(" ");

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(ss);

        Map<Integer,String> set = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();

        int i =0;
        for(String str : list)
        {
            set.put(str.length(), str);
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
            i++;
        }


        Set<Integer> keys = set.keySet();

        System.out.println(keys);
        System.out.println(set);

        Object j[]= keys.toArray();

        Arrays.sort(j);

        Object max = j[j.length-1];

        set.get(max);

        System.out.println("Tha longest word is "+set.get(max));
        System.out.println("Length is  "+max);
```